# Laravel - Can't install User Agent package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, package, vendor

After failing many times trying to get Mobile Detect to work I figured this would be easier: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-agent/

I followed the simple steps and it says the class can't be found. What did I miss?

Comment: Can you post the error and have you tried running composer dumpautoload

Comment: Just a basic class not found error. Maybe I did everything in the wrong order. Should I dump the auto load immediately after the composer update?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, but it's worth trying in case something random happened. Which class is it not finding?

Comment: can you mention step by step process which you followed

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, so I started from scratch and used dump-autoload on both composer and artisan before adding the respective code to app/config/app.php and it worked.